# Multilingual in Drupal: Can't have a node and it's translations as frontpage. How to?

Tags: drupal, multilingual, frontpage

1. i built a page in **Persian**.

   2. set it's path to **front**
   3. set drupal frontpage to **/front**
   4. everything is O.K. in mysite.com/fa
   5. i translate the page to **en**

problem arises. now the path of Persian page changes to default node/33. now in language's frontpage drupal says **Can't find the page.**

i tried to set path **front** to the translated english page. but it did not helped.
i alse tried to assign path **fa/front** to my Persian page.

nothing helped.

translating brakes path in other nodes.

how can i have these pages **/front** and **/fa/front** translated of each other as the same time?

Answer (score 1):

I also experienced 'path not found' issue for localized pages when addressing them by path alias (only reproduced for the default language pages).
I fixed it by setting 'path prefix' for the default language (admin/settings/language/edit/en for English).
However I'm not sure you have the same problem, if so - try to set 'node/33' path for your front page instead of using alias.